# Add rows with value=0 to have the same number of rows by group dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with groups by country and rows with date, in some countries there are no rows for some dates, I would like to fill these missing rows with a 0 value

For example:

```
dd <- tibble( region=rep("Aus",8), date=c("2000-11-01","2000-12-01","2001-01-01","2001-02-01","2001-03-01","2001-04-01","2001-05-01","2001-06-01"), value=runif(8))
dd <- bind_rows(dd,tibble( region=rep("Est",6), date=c("2000-11-01","2001-01-01","2001-02-01","2001-04-01","2001-05-01","2001-06-01"), value=runif(6)))
```

I need to add two rows for the group `Est`  with missing dates `2000-12-01` `2001-03-01` with `value=0`

I can't figure out how to make this for a general case using dplyr or base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dd %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_fill = 0) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -region)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
   region name        value
   <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>
 1 Aus    2000-11-01 0.313 
 2 Aus    2000-12-01 0.842 
 3 Aus    2001-01-01 0.314 
 4 Aus    2001-02-01 0.757 
 5 Aus    2001-03-01 0.968 
 6 Aus    2001-04-01 0.169 
 7 Aus    2001-05-01 0.697 
 8 Aus    2001-06-01 0.873 
 9 Est    2000-11-01 0.132 
10 Est    2000-12-01 0     
11 Est    2001-01-01 0.0785
12 Est    2001-02-01 0.378 
13 Est    2001-03-01 0     
14 Est    2001-04-01 0.580 
15 Est    2001-05-01 0.536 
16 Est    2001-06-01 0.109
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2023, you can use `tidyr::complete()` to achieve the same result in a more readable and flexible way.

Here is the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dd <- tibble( region=rep("Aus",8), date=c("2000-11-01","2000-12-01","2001-01-01","2001-02-01","2001-03-01","2001-04-01","2001-05-01","2001-06-01"), value=runif(8))
dd <- bind_rows(dd,tibble( region=rep("Est",6), date=c("2000-11-01","2001-01-01","2001-02-01","2001-04-01","2001-05-01","2001-06-01"), value=runif(6)))

tidyr::complete(dd, region, date, fill=list(value=0))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 3
#>    region date         value
#>    <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1 Aus    2000-11-01 0.884  
#>  2 Aus    2000-12-01 0.400  
#>  3 Aus    2001-01-01 0.348  
#>  4 Aus    2001-02-01 0.0991 
#>  5 Aus    2001-03-01 0.0854 
#>  6 Aus    2001-04-01 0.908  
#>  7 Aus    2001-05-01 0.729  
#>  8 Aus    2001-06-01 0.683  
#>  9 Est    2000-11-01 0.511  
#> 10 Est    2000-12-01 0      
#> 11 Est    2001-01-01 0.00635
#> 12 Est    2001-02-01 0.0997 
#> 13 Est    2001-03-01 0      
#> 14 Est    2001-04-01 0.723  
#> 15 Est    2001-05-01 0.861  
#> 16 Est    2001-06-01 0.776
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>